# Python format not replacing values

Tags: python

I am trying to format a string in python, but the values are not being replaced.

Here is my example...

```
uid = results[0][0]

query = """
     SELECT  
        m.whiteUid,
        m.blackUid,
        u1.displayName AS whiteDisplayName,
        u2.displayName AS blackDisplayName,
        m.created,
        m.modified
     FROM matches m
     INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.uid = m.whiteUid
     INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.uid = m.blackUid
     WHERE
         m.whiteUid = {uid} OR m.blackUid = {uid} OR m.id = {uid}
    """
query.format(uid=uid)
```

When I run this query the string {uid} still exists in all locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this:

`query = query.format(...)`.

The format method just returns the formatted string, it doesn't change `self`.

Answer (score 1):

String is immutable.

Use f string. It's recommended.

```
query = f"""
  SELECT  
    m.whiteUid,
    m.blackUid,
    u1.displayName AS whiteDisplayName,
    u2.displayName AS blackDisplayName,
    m.created,
    m.modified
  FROM matches m
  INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.uid = m.whiteUid
  INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.uid = m.blackUid
  WHERE
    m.whiteUid = {uid} OR m.blackUid = {uid} OR m.id = {uid}
"""
```

Comment: Showing invalid syntax

Comment: Indented it now

Answer (score 0):

If using python3 I would recommend f-Strings (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
uid = results[0][0]

query = f"""
  SELECT  
    m.whiteUid,
    m.blackUid,
    u1.displayName AS whiteDisplayName,
    u2.displayName AS blackDisplayName,
    m.created,
    m.modified
  FROM matches m
  INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.uid = m.whiteUid
  INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.uid = m.blackUid
  WHERE
    m.whiteUid = {uid} OR m.blackUid = {uid} OR m.id = {uid}
"""

print(query)
```

NOTE: take into account that it already tries to inject the value of any variabale defined in, so it must exists already.